# How to increase breakpoint limit in current WinDbg?

Tags: windbg

As a driver developer WinDbg is one of my best friends.

Now starting with Windows 8, I installed the new WDK and wanted to use its new WinDbg. It has some nice features like remote debugging over the network.

But while using it, I became shocked when I realized that I can only activate 32 breakpoints. The following message is shown:

```
*******************************************************************************
* You have attempted to enable   33 KD breakpoints, which exceeds the         *
* currently supported limit of   32 breakpoints for Windows kernel debugging. *
* Breakpoints exceeding this limit are ignored.                               *
* Please disable/clear breakpoints until you are within the supported limit.  *
*******************************************************************************
```

This was not the case in earlier versions. Is there a way around this? A option I did not found yet, a registry key or maybe I can patch the executable?

Answer (score 1):

Interesting. The warning messages are coming from dbgeng!AddBreakpoint and in stepping through the code it looks like the limit of 32 is hard coded:

```
cmp     esi, 20h
jbe     short loc_100A5721
push    offset asc_10038758 ; "***************************************"...
call    ?WarnOut@@YAXPBGZZ
pop     ecx
push    esi
push    offset aYouHaveAttempt ; "* You have attempted to enable %4u KD b"...
call    ?WarnOut@@YAXPBGZZ
push    20h
push    offset aCurrentlySuppo ; "* currently supported limit of %4u brea"...
call    ?WarnOut@@YAXPBGZZ
push    offset aBreakpointsExc ; "* Breakpoints exceeding this limit are "...
call    ?WarnOut@@YAXPBGZZ
```

I suspect that just patching this one check would NOT be sufficient, but I haven't looked any further to confirm that.

Answer (score 0):

You can place int 3 (byte 0xCC) at any address by the following command: eb [address] cc

Make sure to restore the original byte when you hit int 3.

Comment: I know this, but less comfortable, especially because WinDbg's bm command uses wildcards.

Comment: Yeah it's not convenient specially if you want to use additional breakpoint options. However you can work around the wildcard symbols by using "x" to get the address.